# Free Energy Dissipation of Langevin

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Let $\rho(t,\cdot)$ be a distribution over $\mathbb{R}%d$ at time $t$ of the Langevin stochastic process, i.e

$$ \partial_t \rho_t = \text{div}(\nabla \rho_t+\rho_t\nabla V) $$

for some uniformly convex $V$.  How can I see that the derivative (along solutions of the above equation) of the associated free energy

$$F(\rho):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho( \log \rho+V)dx$$

is

$$ \partial_t F(\rho_t)=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho_t\|\nabla \big( \log \rho_t +V \big)\|^2dx~~~~~?$$

Comment: Is $dx$ supposed to represent a line element? If so, along which path are we taking the integration? You need to make things a little more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $F = \int_\Omega\,(\log\rho + V)\rho\, dx$ you have
\begin{align}
F_t &= \int_\Omega\, (\rho_t + \rho V_t)\, dx + \int_\Omega\, (\log\rho + V)\rho_t\, dx \\
&= \int_\Omega\, \rho V_t\, dx + \int_\Omega\, (1 + \log\rho + V)\rho_t\, dx \\
&= \int_\Omega\, \rho V_t\, dx + \int_\Omega\, (1 + \log\rho + V)\operatorname{div}(\nabla\rho + \rho\nabla V)\, dx \\
&= \int_\Omega\, \rho V_t\, dx \\
&\quad+ \int_\Omega\, \operatorname{div}((1 + \log\rho + V)(\nabla\rho + \rho\nabla V))\, dx \\
&\quad- \int_\Omega\, \nabla(1 + \log\rho + V)\cdot(\nabla\rho + \rho\nabla V)\, dx.
\end{align}
In the final integral, $\nabla(1 + \log\rho + V) = \rho^{-1}(\nabla\rho + \rho\nabla V)$, so the integral can be written $\int_\Omega\,\rho^{-1} \vert\nabla\rho + \rho\nabla V\vert^2\, dx$ or as $\int_\Omega\,\rho\vert\nabla\log \rho + \nabla V\vert^2\, dx.$

This differs from the stated result. I don't know enough about the problem, but presumably things vanish at the boundary, and the divergence theorem lets you take care of the associated integral. As far as the integral of $\rho V_t$ goes I have no idea.

*Edit*

The post now seems to use $\rho_t$ to refer to what conventionally would be denoted $\rho(t, \,\cdot\,)$, different from the time derivative here.

Comment: Usually at least in theoretical physics $V_t$ would just be zero, since it is essentially the influence of the outside environment on the particle.